# Windows Form how return null to picturebox

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

**UserControl1**

```
public void showpictures()
{
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=BRAIANX-PC;Initial Catalog=teste;Integrated Security=True");

            SqlCommand comand = new SqlCommand("select photto2 from dbo.tblProduct",conn);
            conn.Open();                    
            SqlDataReader reader = comand.ExecuteReader();

            Image imagem = null;
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                byte[] foto = (byte[])reader["photto2"];

                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(foto);
                imagem = Image.FromStream(ms);
            }
            pictureBox1.Image = imagem;               
    }
}
```

**Form**

```
SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("SELECT  tblCategory.Categoryname, tblProduct.Productname,tblProduct.Sinopse,tblProduct.Photto2 FROM tblCategory INNER JOIN tblProduct ON tblCategory.Categoryid = tblProduct.Categoryid where tblCategory.Categoryname= '" + btn.Text + "'", cn);

try
{
    SqlDataReader dr = cm.ExecuteReader();

    flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Clear();
    flowLayoutPanel2.Update();
    while (dr.Read())     
    {
        UserControl1 user = new UserControl1();
       // user.Nnovo  = (string)dr["Productname"].ToString();//Adds the values ​​of the database in label1 the UserControl
       // user.LastName = (string)dr["Sinopse"].ToString(); //Adds the values ​​of the database in label2 the UserControl

       user.Nnovo = (string)dr[0].ToString();
       user.LastName = (string)dr[1].ToString();
       user.showpictures();

        flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(user);
```

How I can retrieve image `null` of PictureBox?

Because have this problem:

> It is not possible to convert an object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.Byte[]'

Is there another way to improve this code? I do not know much about byte arrays?

Comment: You're missing the catch block of your try/catch statement in the second block.

Comment: Just check if it's DBNull, and if it is, don't attempt the cast. Or do a `if( val is byte[] )`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check whether the value returned is `DbNull.Value`:

```
byte[] foto;

if (reader["photto2"] != DbNull.Value)
{
    foto = (byte[])reader["photto2"];
}
else
{
    foto = null;
}
```

Or shorter, with the ternary operator:

```
byte[] foto = reader["photto2"] != DbNull.Value ? (byte[])reader["photto2"] : null;
```

Or, even nicer, with a soft cast:

```
byte[] foto = reader["photto2"] as byte[];
```